# Word or phrase for someone claimed as one of a city's own

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word that captures not merely that a person was considered *great*, but also in some sense *belongs* to a place?

[Isambard Kingdom Brunel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isambard_Kingdom_Brunel) was born in Portsmouth, and lived much of his life in London, where he died, and yet the city of Bristol hosts many of his most famous feats of engineering. Accordingly, Bristol often claims Brunel as one of its own. Not a resident, not a citizen, but... a *luminary*? A *celebrity*? Something like *adopted son*, but with added reverance?

Example sentence:

"The famous engineer Brunel was one of Bristol's _________"?

Comment: ...one of  Bristol’s most prominent figures.

Comment: [Golden boy?](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/golden) "MW—Having talents that promise great success—often used with boy."

Comment: 'Luminary' is not bad.  He is certainly closely associated with the city:  the suspension bridge, the SS Great Britain and the Great Western railway are obvious attractions in the city.  I am not sure he was all that interested in Bristol itself.  What about about Colston, famous for Bristol's unfortunately prominent part in the 'triangular' slave trade?  Is he a 'luminary'.

Comment: Did he ever live in Bristol or was it just his engineering that featured there?

Comment: @Tuffy If someone told me he was a Bristol luminary, I would assume he was a current or former citizen, not just that his work was featured there. I don't think there's a word for this specific relationship.

Answer (score 3):

One such phrase, though masculine only as far as I know, is ***favorite son***. [AHD (2)](https://www.wordnik.com/words/favorite%20son) has:

> A famous man viewed proudly by his hometown for his achievements.

Comment: Yes but in this case it is not his hometown but a different one.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica Maybe he was adopted? (-:

Comment: @JimMack - I'm not sure "Bristol's favourite step-child" quite has the same ring to it ;))

Answer (score 3):

**an honorary citizen**.

> [**honorary**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/honorary) "An honorary title or membership of a group is given to someone without their needing to have the necessary qualifications, usually because of their public achievements."

"Isambard Brunel was an honorary citizen of Bristol"

Comment: The blank is in the wrong place, +1. "Beloved as an honorary citizen, the famous engineer Brunel was one of Bristol's most [inspirational, prolific, prominent, etc.] architects." ("beloved honorary citizen" : only 65 hits but it sure rings a bell)